# Why is the "else" line giving an invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax-error, indentation, if-statement

I'm having this error:

```
File "zzz.py", line 70
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The line which causes the problem is marked with a comment in the code:

```
def FileParse(self, table_file):
    vars={}
    tf = open(table_file, 'r')
    for line in tf:
        if line.startswith("#") or line.strip() == "": pass
        elif line.startswith("n_states:"):
            self.n_states = str(line[9:].strip())
        elif line.startswith("neighborhood:"):
            self.neighborhood = str(line[13:].strip())
        elif line.startswith("symmetries:"):
            self.symmetries = str(line[11:].strip())
        elif line.startswith("var "):
            line = line[4:]
            ent = line.replace('=',' ').\
            replace('{',' ').\
            replace(',',' ').\
            replace(':',' ').\
            replace('}',' ').\
            replace('\n','').split()
            vars[ent[0]] = []
            for e in ent[1:]:
                if e in vars: vars[ent[0]] += vars[e]
                else: 
                    vars[ent[0].append(int(e))]     
        else:
            rule = line.strip().split(",")
            for k in vars.keys():
                if k in rule:
                    for i in vars[k]:
                        change = rule.replace(k, i)
                        change = [int(x) for x in change]
                        w.rules.append(Rule(change[:5],change[5])

                else: # line which causes the problem

                    rule = [int(x) for x in rule]
                    w.rules.append(Rule(rule[:5],rule[5]))                  
    tf.close()
    self.parse_status "OK"
    return w.rules
```

`w.rules` is variable which is assigned to "World" class.

To be honest I have no idea why I get this. Before everything was fine and now that error shows up after adding some extra instructions in other indented blocks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because you left out a closing brace

```
w.rules.append(Rule(change[:5],change[5]) )
```

Comment: Yeah, indeed. So simple...

Thanks! ;)

Comment: Interesting how many upvotes this has. I'm guessing it means a lot of people have this exact issue - you'd think Python would improve its error message so that fewer people would hit this.

Comment: Agree @ArtOfWarfare . Seems like that the exception mechanism of Python, would need an update in order to map this case. Easy for me to say, since that I'm not a maintainer of the project hahaha but indeed, I believe that this issue deserves an attention.

Comment: I got exactly the same thing, and wow- I mean @ArtOfWarfare and ivanleoncz exactly

Answer (score 4):

The previous line, `w.rules.append(Rule(change[:5],change[5])`, is missing a close paren.

Answer (score 4):

While you're at it, there is another typo.  You probably want:

```
self.parse_status "OK"
```

To be:

```
self.parse_status = "OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra spaces/lines and re-indent the if/else statements. This worked for me.

(I tried the other solutions here but none worked. My braces were fine.)